# Dead-beat Feedback Design

Tags: control-theory

Suppose we have the following discrete time system in state space form:

\begin{align*}
x[k+1] = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_k\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} x[k]  + \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} u[k]
\end{align*}

where $a_k = \begin{cases}
    -1,& \text{if } \text{mod(k,2) = 0}\\
    0,              & \text{if } \text{mod(k,2) = 1}
\end{cases}
$

My aim is to design a feedback law in the form of
\begin{equation}
 u[k] = -K[k]x[k]
\end{equation}
which makes the above system LTI and the system behavior dead-beat.

Here is my attempt:
\begin{align*}
x[k+1] &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_k\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} x[k]  - \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
K_1[k] & K_2[k]
\end{bmatrix} x[k] \\
&= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
-K_1[k] & a_k - K_2[k]\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}}_{F} x[k]
\end{align*}
To make the system LTI, we need to have constant coefficient matrix. Hence choose
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
K_1 \\
K_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
K_1 \\
a_k
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Furthermore, for the dead-beat response, the eigenvalues should be at zero. So,
\begin{align*}
|zI - F| = \begin{bmatrix}
z + K_1 & 0\\
-1 & z-2
\end{bmatrix} = z^2
\end{align*}
which seems impossible. Any idea for such a design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your system is controllable, you can place the eigenvalues wherever you want. The issue with your design is that you set $K_2(k)=a_k$, which leads to an infeasible problem. What about letting $K_1(k)=2$ and $K_2(k)=4+a_k$?